# How to select time ranges in android?

Tags: android, timepicker, android-seekbar

I know I can use `TimePicker` to select time in android. But, I have to pick a time interval like `from-to`. Ex `03:00 AM-09:00 AM`.
I have seen a something like in the following figure.
[image]

I came to know it is `RangeSeekBar`. I don't know how to use it to select time range and don't know how to set `RangeValues` to this `RangeSeekBar`. If anybody familiar with this custom widget means please do help me. At this moment I'm stuck in my project because don't know how to implement this. Thanks.

Comment: your answer in your question just refer RangeSeekBar  code is https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar/blob/master/rangeseekbar/src/main/java/com/yahoo/mobile/client/android/util/rangeseekbar/RangeSeekBar.javahere

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/